Merge statement for merging bronze and silver layers
I'm trying to implement logic for building slowly changing dimensions using the Merge statement. In my bronze or staging layer I receive a full raw extract every day. See an example below.
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS bronze_customers (
    Id INT, 
    CustomerName STRING, 
    ContactName STRING,
    Address STRING,
    City STRING,
    PostalCode STRING,
    Country STRING,
    loading_date DATE
) USING DELTA;

Within the Silver layer I want to keep track of what records were added, changed or deleted. I would like to use the following table structure for this (start_date, end_date and is_current have been added).
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS silver_customers (
    Id INT, 
    CustomerName STRING, 
    ContactName STRING,
    Address STRING,
    City STRING,
    PostalCode STRING,
    Country STRING,
    start_date DATE,
    end_date DATE,
    is_current INT
) USING DELTA;

For the merge, I'm using this statement:
%%sql
MERGE INTO silver_customers AS c
USING
(  
    SELECT cc.Id AS mergekey,
           cc.Id, cc.CustomerName, cc.ContactName, cc.Address, cc.City, cc.PostalCode, cc.Country, cc.loading_date as start_date,
           '' as end_date,
           1 as is_current
    FROM bronze_customers cc  
    UNION ALL  
    SELECT NULL as mergekey,  
           cc.Id, cc.CustomerName, cc.ContactName, cc.Address, cc.City, cc.PostalCode, cc.Country, cc.loading_date as start_date,
           '' as enddate,
           1 as is_current
    FROM bronze_customers cc
) ud
ON c.id = ud.mergekey
AND c.is_current = 1
WHEN MATCHED
    THEN UPDATE SET is_current = 0,
                    end_date = ud.start_date
WHEN NOT MATCHED
AND mergekey is null
    THEN INSERT *

Issue however is I'm getting this error when no records were changed in the source system:

Cannot perform Merge as multiple source rows matched and attempted to
modify the same target row in the Delta table in possibly conflicting
ways.

Is this as intended? And is a merge the best way to approach this?

Assume from the medallion architecture terms you are using Databricks?

"SELECT NULL as mergekey, " and "ON c.id = ud.mergekey"... the second part of the UNION ALL is thus useless... nothing will ever be equal to NULL

Youre keying off of mergekey and your ud subquery is producing more than one row for each distinct mergekey. How do you want to deal with those? You can't have more than one record for each mergekey since your system doesn't know which of those multiple records it should use to perform the update. Also, to @p3consulting's point that UNION where you make your mergekey NULL doesn't make any sense at all. You can't join on NULL and even if you could, you would have every record in your bronze_customer table sharing a duplicate NULL mergekey.

@Error_2646, I'm using Microsoft Fabric (Spark 3.4 runtime).

@JNevill, You can't have more than one record for each mergekey since your system doesn't know which of those multiple records it should use to perform the update.
What would you then recommend? Bronze is overwritten every day and it's not clear what records were updated. So, I need to compare both, which could result into multiple records...

@Erhnam It's not clear to me how your approach can achieve scd2 given what you've described. Maybe I'm missing something. A common approach is to compute a hash using all the columns you want to check for changes on. But whatever you do at some point you have to look at "does this record in bronze have all the same data as what we've already loaded in silver". And deletes are a whole other can of worms.

I can't suggest anything since I don't know your data. This is a data issue, not a code issue. If, for instance, every time something changes in your source system you get a delta record, then SCD2 is probably not the right format for storage since you know for a fact that something has changed on each record. Just INSERT to keep all history. If there is a chance that nothing has changed between two identical mergekey records in bronze, then do a SELECT DISTINCT in your merge's subquery to compress those records into one. If you are still getting duplicates... there is no silver bullet.

The issue is due to MERGE statement is trying to update multiple rows in the target table ("silver_customers") with  same Id and is_current values.
Solution: Handle duplicate keys in Source table data
Possible approaches are:

Deduplicate Source Data: Only unique records for each Id on each load.
Filter Unchanged Rows: Exclude rows which haven't changed compared to is_current = 1 row in the target table
Use ROW_NUMBER to identify the most recent change

WITH ranked_updates AS (
    SELECT
        cc.Id AS mergekey,
        cc.Id, 
        cc.CustomerName, 
        cc.ContactName, 
        cc.Address, 
        cc.City, 
        cc.PostalCode, 
        cc.Country, 
        cc.loading_date as start_date,
        '' as end_date,
        1 as is_current,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY cc.Id ORDER BY cc.loading_date DESC) as rn
    FROM bronze_customers cc
)
MERGE INTO silver_customers AS c
USING (
    SELECT *
    FROM ranked_updates
    WHERE rn = 1 -- Only consider the most recent record for each Id
) ud
ON c.id = ud.mergekey
AND c.is_current = 1
WHEN MATCHED
    THEN UPDATE SET is_current = 0,
                    end_date = ud.start_date
WHEN NOT MATCHED
AND mergekey is null
    THEN INSERT (Id, CustomerName, ContactName, Address, City, PostalCode, Country, start_date, end_date, is_current)
         VALUES (ud.Id, ud.CustomerName, ud.ContactName, ud.Address, ud.City, ud.PostalCode, ud.Country, ud.start_date, ud.end_date, ud.is_current);

Is MERGE the Best Approach?
Yes MERGE is a standard approach for SCD requirements, especially for SCD type 2 changes. Challenge is ensuring that source table is not having duplicate entries.
